# How to setup multicast for this network?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, networking, routing, multicast

I have a Network like this at my home.

[image]

```
# ip route show
default via 192.168.0.1 dev enp1s0
192.168.0.0/24 dev enp1s0  proto kernel  scope link  src 192.168.0.110
192.168.1.0/24 dev enp3s0  proto kernel  scope link  src 192.168.1.10
```

What I'm doing with linux box in middle is that monitoring internet usage and limit data when a limit is reached using iptables and tc

Recently I have added a DVB card to one of my PC and using DVBdream software I tried to stream Channels to other devices using Lan streaming

On the same PC this works fine.

[image]
[image]

But if I try to open udp://@224.0.0.10:1234 with VLC on another PC, its not working

I tried by adding multicast network to route list but this did nothing

```
route -n add -net 224.0.0.0 netmask 240.0.0.0 dev enp3s0
```

also linux Kernel has these enabled

```
CONFIG_IP_MULTICAST=y
CONFIG_IP_PIMSM_V2=y
CONFIG_IP_MROUTE=y
# CONFIG_IP_MROUTE_MULTIPLE_TABLES is not set
```

if i run this command on linux router

```
tcpdump -i enp3s0 ip multicast
```

i can see output like this

```
13:50:37.072348 IP 192.168.1.100 > igrp-routers.mcast.net: udp
13:50:37.072458 IP 192.168.1.100 > igrp-routers.mcast.net: udp
13:50:37.072588 IP 192.168.1.100 > igrp-routers.mcast.net: udp
13:50:37.072703 IP 192.168.1.100 > igrp-routers.mcast.net: udp
13:50:37.072838 IP 192.168.1.100 > igrp-routers.mcast.net: udp
13:50:37.072953 IP 192.168.1.100 > igrp-routers.mcast.net: udp
13:50:37.073083 IP 192.168.1.100 > igrp-routers.mcast.net: udp
13:50:37.073195 IP 192.168.1.100 > igrp-routers.mcast.net: udp
13:50:37.073205 IP 192.168.1.100 > igrp-routers.mcast.net: udp
```

Is it possible to Multicast on this system and view channels with other PC's? if so how can i enable multicast on this system?

Note: I tried broadcast and it works but network is getting lag due to unnecessary data transfer to all devices connected to it.

Regards

Comment: https://networkengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/50198/how-to-setup-multicast-for-this-network

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Very briefly:

1) Multicast is not forwarded via routing, so you can set routes until you are blue in the face, nothing will change.

2) Try on 192.168.1.100 and 196.168.1.112 first, they are in the same segment, it should just work. If not debug, with tcpdump.

3) Is the wireless gateway bridged? If not, you need to install a multicast routing demon, e.g. `smcroute` or `pimd`. I strongly recommend to bridge it, that's the simpler solution.

4) You can test multicasting in general with `ssmping`. Again, use `tcpdump` on all machines to debug.

Comment: As the maintainer for smcroute, pimd, and mrouted I concur, bridging is always easier.  Just watch out for the Linux multicast snooping implementation, you may have to disable it in the bridge.